# Error in FireFox Loading Images

Tags: asp.net, image, firefox

Details of the app are: ASP.NET project, local web server, hosted in IIS locally, using latest FireFox, uses forms authentication.

I'm getting a logon user name/pwd box when trying to access my local web server.  Using the net panel in firebug, I see the issue is with an animated GIF, showing up as 401 unauthorized.  I check the details and this is what I see for this URL:

```
http://localhost/<virtual>/Images/loading.gif
```

I'm getting the following:

Response Headers:

```
Server Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date Thu, 17 Jun 2010 19:02:58 GMT
WWW-Authenticate Negotiate NTLM
Connection close
Content-Length 4046
Content-Type text/html
```

Request headers:

```
Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 115
Connection keep-alive
Referer <correct referer>
Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=ux4bt345qjz4p3u1wm1zgmez; .ASPXFormsAuth=33F12B444040827B8ABF154EE4EDE43B6CA532432EB846987B355097E00256DF0955C76A37BC593EAA961747BF1CC1D8949FF63C6F2CA69D77213EB15B4EDFAF57A83D9E1F88AB8D821C3A09C07EA2EE; .ASPROLES=qTFrGteJydYAE3118WGXbhJthTDdjdtuQ06t4bYVrM1BwIfcEHU1HhnEcs7TqSOaV-fIN5MH3uO57oNVWXDvrhkZ8gQuURuUk_K0TpoR-DEFXuF953Gl9aIilKAdV211jutMNQmhkt2rdPE2tEhHs3pz953fADxjAOyZl7K-AqNvMk3yqJshhKHhJIf-ALMhWIYlrrKy0WsYznUwh3WCtPfzEBD5XzmXU8HVMJ2-ArLjBISuegvSmxvK1PuXBPhoMRMi9Ynaw6xi9ypGk-R6uN0ljOMCGkB2-20WUlFuP0xWTfac_zCTDT00pbpnyjtygnM-LShOXTrZ_mhoRuXfKYEYSodNihwD6SRr19Nm-8uZ5BQ-W81svM17S2C0vc0FaxtiuAcN_vHcsN1OEJeCuVfRjeqzo9xWEViupP3Vh6aOcCm6yrftgw5x94piuCJO7tCfXjJAw5RVUWDBBWv5gmid171F0k-_XZ0CSv7Gm2Eai1BRfogAqQ_MV3tyPv7XVEyJXRXqYGlf1JpkfTW8S8On4E05v9gx9RcdnKHZebiOZwbP1_ho9nG7pMwXysbhjxtxwZ-zLx-v11_rhZw_i5m7iNcLtt4BbFU-sb_crzMpCKGywHIc452Zp1E0kx1Rfx-2eUnaiLiCfGed-QqelO88NYTpJHttGKEfhFrDgmaIXZPJRtuZ-GrS6t3Vla-8qDAVb1p6ovPwoVT4z4BhQyFsk542gDx-uQDw6D0B6zo7lXfcOjtolUxDcLbETsNlYsexZaxFpRSbw7M1ldwL_k92P9wLPlv9mw4NtyhXKJesMu7GjquZuoBN3hO00AqJEe1tKFFtfrvbE5ZH7uNu7myNdtlxRPe3WZe7qukbqHo1
Pragma no-cache
Cache-Control no-cache
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: is the NTFS permissions on the image folder, image itself correct for IIS to read that image?  Does IIS have any special settings for that particular directory/image? (Integrated Auth instead of Anonymous)

Comment: That was it; it wasn't inheriting default permissions.  You may want to move your statement as an answer; I can mark it the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct answer from @Tommy:

is the NTFS permissions on the image folder, image itself correct for IIS to read that image? Does IIS have any special settings for that particular directory/image? (Integrated Auth instead of Anonymous)

Somehow, the ASPNET account lost permissions to those images, hence the challenge and error.